# SQL Server Index Help. How to speed up both WHERE and ORDER BY

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-order-by, query-optimization, where-clause

Thank you for helping me. I have this indexed view that I am selecting from. I created a nonclustered index, but the query has WHERE predicates and ORDER BY requirements. If I have the columns from the WHERE put first on the index, then the ORDER BY is slow and vise-versa. The best that I could find out was having a mix, but the speed isn't quite what I wanted it.

it is like this for example:

```
SELECT apple, banana
FROM indexViewFood
WHERE pickingDate BETWEEN '09/01/2016' AND '10/02/2016' 
  AND aid IN (1,2,3,4)
  AND bid IN (11,12,13,14)
ORDER BY apple, banana
```

right now, I have the index on pickingDate, and then apple:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_food ON (pickingDate, apple) INCLUDE (banana, aid, bid)
```

The index seek has a 3% cost while the sort has a 90% cost. If I put an index of (aid, pickingDate), the execution time is way longer.

The query has to be order by those names. The real query selects from multiple tables as left joins. All the extra data must be slowing down the sort operation. The current run time is five minutes.

Is there other Index combinations I can try? Are there other methodologies that I could try when it comes to WHERE and ORDER By combination? Thank you again

Comment: did you try using the index tuning wizard?

Comment: yup, and I don't trust it some times. An index of (aid, pickingDate) is way slower than my current one

Comment: How many rows does the unfiltered view return? How many rows does the query return?

Comment: I have already add filters when I created the index view. When I do testing, I added all the parameters. So the total row count  is 9,855,256

Comment: Try an index pickingDate, apple, banana INCLUDING aid and bid. The pickingDate will help the filter, the apple,banana will force the sort order in the scan (so no separate sort step needed), and the INCLUDING of aid and bid will enable the index to be used without any primary key lookups

Comment: A similar index I had did have that format, but the performance was a little bit slower. There was still a sort operation. I found out that two columns was best. Thank you

Comment: Keep in mind that adding an index to a view COULD make changes to the underlying tables horribly slow! How long does it take to run the query WITHOUT the index on the view? Wouldn't it be possible optimize the underlying tables to get the (non-indexed) view below the 5 minute mark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

everyone advice underneath my question helped